# Dynamically colouring jTable row

Tags: swing, jtable, tablecellrenderer

In the answer to my previous question, [Coloring jTable row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11135695/coloring-jtable-row), but now I'm unsure as to new question goes here, setting color to row is working. But I want to give it from a for loop, means I want to set color for i'th row. I'm giving the which I have used,

```
for(int i=0;i<serialNumber;i++){
  if((jTable1.getValueAt(i,1).toString()).equals(BidNumber)){
   Enumeration<TableColumn> en = jTable1.getColumnModel().getColumns();
    while (en.hasMoreElements()) {
        TableColumn tc = en.nextElement();

        tc.setCellRenderer(new MyTableCellRenderer());
    }
}
```

It will invoke the method cellrenderer,

```
public class MyTableCellRenderer extends DefaultTableCellRenderer implements TableCellRenderer {

        @Override
        public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
            setBackground(null);
            super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);

              boolean interestingRow = row ==1;



            if (interestingRow) {
                setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
            }

            return this;
        }

    }
```

here I am trying to put color for the row when first column value is equal to the BidNumber, but in cellrenderer(here),it's set as row==1,then every time when the condition is true the 1 st row will be colored..How can I set it for i'th row?

Comment: Do you mean replace the condition `row==1` by `row == i`?

Comment: yes..I want to set color for ith row

Comment: So what is the problem here? Anything preventing you from soing that?

Comment: I cant put row==i,so how can i do that?

Comment: What's preventing you from writing `row==i`? As explained by MadProgrammer, you need to retrieve `i` somehow. From your TableModel, from a Controller, from somewhere else...

Comment: yes that I know..but I am not getting it resolved..everytime error is coming..can you suggest any way?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14125/discussion-between-guillaume-polet-and-tickua)

Answer (score 2):

Change `boolean interestingRow = row ==1` to meet your requirements, where `row == n` would produce the desired result. You must define `n` in some meaningful way

This could come from the table data model or be supplied by other means